# Linux script that counts number of printf parameters for each occurrence

Tags: bash, shell, format, printf

I want to write a script in sh that for each given file, for each printf occurrence, it will count the number of %'s (or alternatively the number of parameters the printf function receives) and rename the printf to printfX, when X is that number.

I got stuck because printf doesn't end with new line...

e.g.

```
printf("hello "
       "world %d\n", 1);
```

should return

```
printf1("hello "
       "world %d\n", 1);
```

Comment: Before trying to come up with a solution, may I ask why you want to do this? If you want to have a wrapper for `printf`, you can do it with variadic arguments so you don't have to write `printf1`, `printf2`, `printf3` etc.

Comment: In general I want to achieve the following - for each instance of printf I want to eliminate the format string and all I want to be left with is the number of parameters and the parameters.
e.g. printf("hello %d %c",hello, char) => printf2(2,hello,char);

Comment: How would you then know the type of the parameter? What would you do with `printf("%s %d", str, num);`?

Comment: actually I intend not to support %s (for this specific usage it is OK)

Comment: even so, `printf("%d %c", num, ch);` prints something like `12 x` while yours cannot differentiate between the two. Are you trying to print everything as `int`? You know better the context of the usage for this, but my gut says there is a better solution for what you are asking. If you tell us why you want to do this, we may offer you a more elegant solution. ;)

Comment: I will lose the type - printfX is a macro (named differently... printfX is just an example) that does a casting to ulong for all the params, and because I don't support %s, the casting will not result in any data loss this way).

Comment: If you have one number that can never happen, say `0xf0000000`, you can do: `#define MY_PRINTF(format, ...) my_printf(0, __VA_ARGS__, 0xf0000000)` and implement `my_printf` as `void my_printf(int dummy, ...);`. Then inside `my_printf`, use `va_list`, start getting the parameters until you hit `0xf0000000`. Note that all parameters are automatically promoted to `int`, so make sure you read `int` by `int`. Your problem would then become renaming `printf` to `MY_PRINTF` which a simple `sed` can do.

Comment: If I'll go the way you've suggested (and that I've already considered) I can't see how can I traverse the __va_args__ (given I dont have the format string - the main idea of my question is to lose the format string and still maintain the parameters) without knowing their size?
The way I described above will give me the ability to up-cast all the params to the biggest type, so that I could go through the __va_args__.

Comment: I'm not sure actually. I know that all integer types get promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int`), except `long long` (maybe `long` also?) when passed through `...`. If you don't have long long, it shouldn't be a problem. Better check the standard.

Comment: I do have unsinged long long int, and atually it is the biggest type, so I decided to cast to this type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple (= as in script) solution for this because to parse C code, you need an [LL(1) parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser).

But you can format all the code in the same way so your script can handle the different cases. So what you should do first is find all lines with `printf` but without `);`:

```
grep "printf" ...files... | grep -v ");"
```

Then fix these files until you don't get any output any more.

Comment: Move the original file to a new place and write a new file. PS: `cut` and `grep` are no parers, they are mere input filters. For one, they can't backtrack and process recursive token trees.

Comment: Since I have no idea what you can't see, I can't help :-)

Comment: I can't see how to solve the problem I presented...  the answer you provided is not practical because it will obviously break in the future - I can't assume that from now on all the programmers using my code will use a one line printf convention...

Comment: Create a test case which runs the check script and makes sure it doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, a simple Perl script to calculate the number of % characters in double quotes before a comma or closing paren.

```
perl -0777pe 's/printf\s*\(\s*\"((?:[^"]*\"\s*\")*[^"]*)\"\s*([,)]\s*)/
  my ($f, $c, $t) = ($1, $1, $2);
  sprintf("printf%i(\"%s\"%s", ($c =~ tr-%--), $f, $t) /ges'  files ...
```

This will substitute inside quoted strings, comments, etc; it will catch `fprintf` and `sprintf` and `myownsacredprintf` as well as plain `printf`.