# Is there a function to count number of parameters for a printf format string?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio

Say, if I do the following:

```
const char *strFmt = "Value=%d, str=%s, v=%I64d. Is 100%% true";
printf(strFmt, 1, "name", -1);
```

Is there a function that simply returns how many parameters are needed for `strFmt` without filling them in?

Comment: you could count the number of `%` that isn't escaped by another `%`.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I can obviously do that... except that it is never safe to assume that the current format will never change. In other words, who can guarantee that they won't come up with a new format, something like `%%i` in the future? That is why I was looking for a built-in function to do that...

Comment: @c00000fd: `%%i` means a literal `%` followed by an `i`. Its meaning can't change. What you can do is return an error if you see any escapes without defined meanings, since these are the only forms that could be assigned new meanings in the future (and they're dangerous to use now anyway since the behavior is undefined).

Comment: @DanielA.White not quite: `"%*.*f"` takes 3 args, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason for wanting the number of required parameters is to check one's code. C runtime libraries do this as a *side-effect* of the `printf` function.  Source for those (as well as for similar printf-like functions such as [`StrAllocVsprintf`](http://lynx.isc.org/current/breakout/WWW/Library/Implementation/HTString.c) in Lynx) can be found easily enough.

Because `printf` is a varargs function, there is no predefined prototype which tells the "right" number of parameters.
If there are too few parameters, bad things can happen ("undefined behavior"), while extra ones may be ignored.  Most modern compilers provide some help, in the form of compile-time warnings.

There is no **standard** function to count the number of required parameters.  The question has been asked before, e.g.,

- [Linux script that counts number of printf parameters for each occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886392/linux-script-that-counts-number-of-printf-parameters-for-each-occurrence)
- [Passing too many arguments to printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578970/passing-too-many-arguments-to-printf)

For whatever historical reason, the function also has (apparently) not been provided by any compiler suite.  In most cases, this is because `printf` formats are usually checked by the compiler (or static analysis tools such as `lint`).  Not all compilers do these checks.  A few can be told using that some functions aside from `printf` and its standard relatives are "printf-like".  Visual Studio lacks that feature, but can do *some* printf-checking (not a lot according to [Is there any way to make visual C++ (9.0) generate warnings about printf format strings not matching type of printf's args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282090/is-there-any-way-to-make-visual-c-9-0-generate-warnings-about-printf-format)).

A string constant is not going to be associated by the compiler with the `printf` function.  You could make it a `#define` and reuse the value in an actual `printf` function to get whatever checking the compiler *can* do.

For instance

```
#define strFmt "Value=%d, str=%s, v=%I64d. Is 100%% true"
printf(strFmt, 1, "name", -1);
```

The problem itself is *portable*: if your program also is portable, you can check it with other tools than the Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: I need it for Windows/Visual Studio as I indicated in the tags.